# Backbone SQLite sync override

Tags: sqlite, backbone.js, nw.js

How to override `Backbone.sync` so the data is recorded in an external SQLite database? App works on NW.JS.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question as I'm not clear what you're asking?

Comment: If you change the collection or model changes were recorded in the SQLite database, not WebSQL. Do you understand me?

Comment: This question is still unclear. Explaining the structure of the application would help make things clearer. Where are you expecting the database to live? Are you thinking of completely avoiding Ajax?

Answer (score -1):

I know this was asked a while ago, but in case someone comes up with this need again - you can use localForage (with SQL driver) and localForage-Backbone adapter.